# Is there a large-file disk format that OS X can write and Windows can read?

Tags: windows-7, macos, filesystems

I know that FAT32 does not do large files (>4GB).  Is there a file system that OS X can write to that Windows 7 can read from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format it native OSX format and use this software in W7

http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/

Answer (score 6):

NTFS is supported on OS X ( [using NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/))  & Windows 7

Comment: +1, but was looking for something that could be read on windows with minimal/no installation on the mac (trying to recover data from my mac, moving it to my other computer, a pc - and am unable to install software *on* the mac.  But... I didn't go into that much detail on the question, so still gave you the +1

Comment: @Matt No problem :) as long as you get something which works best for you ::)